# How to handle configuration files with distutils to respect unixen's FHS?

Tags: python, distutils, fhs

Suppose we have a program called `foo`.

If use absolute path:

```
setup(...,
      data_files=[...,
              ('/etc', ['foo.cfg'])]
)
```

Then `foo$ python setup.py --prefix=/usr/local` and we will have `/etc/foo.cfg`.
But we should have `/usr/local/etc/foo.cfg` instead according to [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY).

What if we use a relative path?

```
setup(...,
      data_files=[...,
              ('etc', ['foo.cfg'])]
)
```

Then if we use the default install path, i.e. install to /usr, we will have `/usr/etc/foo.cfg`.  Bad
luck again.

So how to do it right?

P.S. To avoid make the problem more complicated, we assume that this program
`foo` cannot run under non unix environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sub-classing `distutils.command.install.install` is not strictly necessary. Instead, `data_files` could be passed to `setup`, as per `distutils` documentation on ['Installing Additional Files'](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files).

e.g.

```
setup(
    ...
    data_files = [
        (conf_path, ['foo.cfg'])
    ]
)
```

where `conf_path` is calculated as per your own requirements. i.e. construct it by testing `sys.prefix` (instead of `self.prefix`), like @weakish did above.

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is no easy way.  The problem is that config files are special data
files and they deserve special treatment.

So, write our own class:

```
class myinstall(distutils.command.install.install):
    if self.prefix == '/usr':
        self.conf_prefix = '/etc'
    else:
        self.conf_prefix = self.prefix + '/etc'

    install.finalize_options(self)

    def install_conf(self):
        self.mkpath((self.root or '') + self.conf_prefix)
        for file in self.distribution.conf_files:
        dest = (self.root or '') + self.conf_prefix + '/' +
            os.path.basename(file)
        self.copy_file(file, dest)

    # blah blah blah
```

Then:

```
setup(# blah blah blah
  conf_files = ['foo.cfg']
  cmdclass = {'install': myinstall,
      # blah blah blah
  }
)
```